# Date Time picker automatically changes the language according to UI Language C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I'm using windows application datetime picker.
When opened in a Laptop with Arabic UI it changes the date time picker to Arabic Language.
I want that the date time picker language should always be English and it should not change according to the UI Language.

Answer (score 2):

DateTimePicker takes OS culture. so if your Laptop is set up for Arabic it'll use that.

[You can try changing the culture for a thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentculture?view=net-7.0).

[Info about Culture class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-7.0)

Comment: I changed the uiCulture but still datetime picker doesn't change

Comment: Can you share your code?